# Eccentricity of an ellipse.with b > a

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I have the following ellipse : $\frac{(x-3)^2}{\frac{9}{4}} + \frac{(y+4)^2}{\frac{25}{4}}=1$

In this case, b > a. It says that to find the eccentricity I must use $\frac{c}{a}$ but I think this is only valid when a>b. What'S the formula to find the eccentricity in my case ?

Comment: probably enough to exchange the roles of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: You mean e= c/b right ?

Comment: Presumably, yes.

Comment: Ok, thanks  again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for eccentricity is always (distance between foci)/(length of major axis).

Comment: Oh ok it seems to work ! Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

In this case, $a=\frac 52$ and the major semi-axis is parallel to the $y$ axis, so the eccentricity is still $$e=\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}=\sqrt{1-\frac {9}{25}}=\frac 45$$

Comment: If $b>a$, then what’s under the radical is negative.

Comment: b is always less than a

Comment: Not if your eqn is $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$.

Comment: The roles of a and b are exchanged, so that the ellipse is taller than it is wide

Comment: yes, that’s what I told OP to do.